# how to destructure react hook so that unused variable no needed to decalare

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useContext(userContext);
```

in this line I just need to use only **setLoggedInUser**. I do not need to use **loggedInUser** here. Now how could I get the **setLoggedInUser** without declaring **loggedInUser**.
Because there are some worning "

> Line 15:12:  'loggedInUser' is assigned a value but never used
> no-unused-vars

How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare it at all

```
const [,setLoggedInUser] = useContext(userContext)
```

Alternatively, this is easy as well:

```
const setLoggedInUser = useContext(userContext)[1]
```

Personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `loggedInUser` with `_`.
It will understand that it is a "throw-away variable."

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need for destructuring:

```
const setLoggedInUser = useContext(userContext)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
const = { setLoggedInUser } = useContext(userContext)
```